# Using Luracast Restler PHP how to specify a default class method for the root path

Tags: php, api, frameworks

I working with Luracast Restler API frame work and cannot figure out how to specify a default behavior for the root directory. For example:

webroot/user - will invoke the class User method get() by default

webroot/ - return a 404

Is there a catch all class/method for the base path?

Comment: OK what just worked was to run the addAPIClass('some_default_class', '') with an empty string as the second parameter. In that class create a method called index(). This is the method that will run. So in index.php it looks like so:

$r->addAPIClass('some_default_class', '');

Not sure if this is to spec but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Creating default class and default action to map it as the root

on your `index.php` (gateway)

```
require_once '../../restler/restler.php';
require_once 'say.php';
$r = new Restler();
//blank string as the second param removes class_name from the URL
$r->addAPIClass('Say','');
$r->handle();
```

This makes Say as the default class, mapped to the root
Next on your API class (Say) define an `index` method, it can also be a `get` method

```
class Say {
    function index($to='world') {
        return "Hello $to!";
    }
}
```

then calling

```
GET index.php
```

will return `Hello World!`

Comment: `function get() {}`
will always override 
`function index(){}`
 and prevent index() from being usable

Comment: @kzap Explanation about get, post, put, delete method prefixes are explained in the [CRUD example](http://help.luracast.com/restler/examples/_006_crud/readme.html) documentation. For information about order of priority and ambiguity read [this thread](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/10)